# rCharts show as blank space

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, rcharts

I have recently been coding in R, and am trying to use rCharts. I have been able to make multiple graphs using rCharts, but I can't get them to show in shiny on a browser or the viewer. This is the code for these particular pages

Server

```
  #LWBS Server Page
  output$LWBSText <- renderText({LWBSsubCali <- subset(Cali, LWBSPercent > input$LWBSRange[1]*.01 & LWBSPercent < input$LWBSRange[2]*.01)
  paste("You have selected a range that goes from", input$LWBSRange[1], "to", input$LWBSRange[2])
  })
  output$LWBSData <- renderDataTable({
    LWBSsubCali <- subset(Cali, LWBSPercent > input$LWBSRange[1]*.01 & LWBSPercent < input$LWBSRange[2]*.01)
    LWBSsubCali})
  output$LWBSText2 <- renderText({
    LWBSsubCali <- subset(Cali, LWBSPercent > input$LWBSRange[1]*.01 & LWBSPercent < input$LWBSRange[2]*.01)
    paste(length(LWBSsubCali$Name))
  })
  #LWBSPlot
  output$LWBSPlot <- renderChart({
    r1<-hPlot(LWBSPercent~Name, data=Cali, color='Name',type='bar')
    #r1$show("server")
    #r1$show(static = FALSE)
    })
```

UI

```
tabPanel("LWBS",
                            sidebarLayout(
                              sidebarPanel(h3("LWBS"), 
                                           p("The left without being seen rate is the percentage of people that enter the hospital, but do not receive treatment. This is usually due to treatment not being issued in an adequet amount of time."),
                                           br(),
                                           sliderInput("LWBSRange",label="Range of LWBS Rate", min=0, max=20, value=c(0,20)),
                                           br(),
                                           br(),
                                           h3("Number of Hospitals: ", textOutput("LWBSText2")),
                                           width=3
                              )    ,

                              mainPanel(h1("Left Without Being Seen Rate"), 
                                        br(),
                                        textOutput("LWBSText") ,
                                        br(),
                                        showOutput("LWBSPlot","highcharts"),
                                        br(),
                                        dataTableOutput("LWBSData"))
                            )),
```